# Trying to get ZeroClipboard working but am having no luck

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard

Here is my code:

**JavaScription:**

```
<script src="/assets/lessons/js/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        clip.setText( '' );
        clip.glue('copy_text_button');
        clip.addEventListener('mouseDown', function() {
            clip.setText($('.modal-pane:visible').text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-pane">
                    <?= $json->parent_connection->english ?>
                    <?php if(isset($sponsor_content->english)): ?>
                        <p><?= $sponsor_content->english ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
<nav class="modal-nav">
                <a href="#" class="modal-btn-close"></a>
                <a href="#" class="modal-btn-english modal-tab">ENG</a>
                <a href="#" class="modal-btn-spanish modal-tab">ESP</a>
                <a href="#" class="modal-btn-copy" id="copy_text_button">Copy Text</a>
            </nav>
```

For some reason its not working and I am not receiving any error messages... any idea why this is happening?

Comment: have you tried to set the text of an input label in modal-pane div and then use clip.setText() for the input tag

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Did you ever figure itout?